# Which code is preferrable to automatically sort NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, core-data

This is a CoreData/SQLite app. I have 2 ways to automatically sort the data in a certain way, on application start-up. Both work as expected, but I would like to ask you which method should be preferred, and why ?

This is the code I made after reading the doc from Apple:

```
[myTableView setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"entity_attribute" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)], nil]];
```

This is somebody else's code which I found on the web:

```
NSSortDescriptor *myDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"entity_attribute" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myDescriptor];
[myController setSortDescriptors:sortedArray];
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two samples you list are doing the exact same thing (and, in the exact same way).

Seems like a preference. Maybe the code you saw online, the author thought it was more readable to split it out into three lines, than to have it all on one big line.

Comment: I was asking because it seemed to me that in the first method, I'm "talking" (setSortDescriptors) to the view, while in the second I'm talking to the controller.

Comment: NSFetchRequest is the only class I know of that consumes that message. If someone (you/the other guy) are making "passthrough" methods of some sort, I'd personally suggest keeping them on a controller - as that doesn't seem to be a concern of the view. But, that's a design decision, and, dependent on your situation / context.

Comment: I see you're sort of new here. If my reply helped you - if you could please click the check mark under the voting arrows to mark my answer as "accepted', I'd appreciate it.